# Any way to restore multiple deleted users from Azure Portal at once

Tags: azure-active-directory

I tried to delete some of my Azure AD users in bulk using a template by following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEUcxFpNwZw).

As explained in that video, I downloaded the csv template and entered the UPN of the users. I successfully deleted the users. Now I want to revoke this action.

I want to restore all the above-deleted users. But I can't find that option.

In bulk operations, I can only see `bulk create, bulk invite and bulk delete`. Is it possible to restore deleted users in bulk at once? If yes, can anyone guide me on the right path?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can find **Bulk Restore** option in **`Deleted Users`** tab. Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/users-bulk-restore).

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is possible to restore deleted users in bulk from Azure Portal.**

You can't find **`Bulk Restore`** option in ***All users -> Bulk Operations*** tab.

[image: Image1]

You can find that option here, ***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Deleted Users -> Bulk Restore***

[image: Image2]

Download `UserRestoreTemplate` csv file. Edit that file by adding **ObjectID** of deleted users you want to restore. Save and upload that file.

Please note that if you enter **UPN** or any other in place of **ObjectID** in that file, bulk operation will fail with error like below:

> **No user with this user name/object ID exists in this group. Change the user name/object ID in the file to match the user name/object ID of an existing user in this group and resubmit your request.**

You can see that the deleted users are restored successfully by checking **All Users** list.

To know more in detail, you can refer this **[MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/users-bulk-restore)**.